# Magento2 - 502 Bad Gateway error - /admin

Tags: magento2

I'm using magento with docker and deploying to a kubernetes cluster.

When I install it it finishes successfully, but when I try to access the admin panel it returns the 502 Bad Gateway error.

I've tried all the settings and without success and on the other hand nothing appears in the error log.

Can anyone help me with suggestions of what it could be?